# In Vim, how to use grep to search keyword which with ONE "?

Tags: vim, cmd, grep

I use the gVim on Windows and installed gnuwin32 to use grep.

At first, everything was ok.
But I found it's very hard to search a keyword which with ONE ".

for example, I want to search keyword **"hero**
In vim's commond mode, input:

> :grep! -n -r --include=*.lua \"hero *

it's not work!

and then i try this in windows command prompt:

```
grep -n -r --include=*.lua \"hero *
```

it works!

Finally, i found that:
when you input

> :grep! -n -r --include=*.lua \"hero *

in vim's command mode, it execute this command:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c (grep.exe -n -r --include=*.lua \^"hero *)
```

and this command is not work!

My question is, how i can escape the keyword correctly so that i can search it in vim's command mode?

Comment: Would using `:vimgrep` instead be an option? See `:h :vimgrep`

Comment: internal search is too slow when searching in many files

Comment: Try dropping the slash? I believe `^` is escape for `cmd.exe` (as that output indicates).

Comment: not work, i try. slash is escape for grep, so it's always needed.

Comment: Have you actually tried vimgrep for your search or are you just using the blanket statement that vimgrep is too slow. I use vimgrep to search a code repository that has over 8200 files, some of which are upwards of 18,000 lines long. Most search takes less than a minute (maybe that is too slow for your needs of course and perhaps we have very different hardware).

Comment: Actually i tryied vimgrep first, and then i found grep is many times faster than vimgrep, so i drop it.I suggest you give it a try.

Comment: If speed is a concern take a look at: [Ack](http://beyondgrep.com/), [Ag the Silver Surfer](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher), and [git grep](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep)? These are all typically much faster than grep.

Comment: Wow I just downloaded a windows port of Ag, The silver Surfer and then the ag.vim plugin. Fastest search I've ever seen!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer by myself.
Either

```
:grep! -n -r --include=*.lua \^"hero *
```

or

```
:grep! -n -r -P --include=*.lua \x22hero *
```

is OK.